# Bootstrap css use only glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

We have a project in late development stage. It has its own css files, with many, many classes and what not in it. Original developer of that css is not available any more.

We just kept adding our classes and styles to a single file.

There is a need for a nice icon set, and bootstrap has exactly what we need. I tried including bootstrap to our project already, but it is a mess when I do that. Everything is clashing I suppose.

Is there a way to include something like minimalist bootstrap that includes only glyphicons
classes?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simply go to Bootstrap's Customization page at http://getbootstrap.com/customize and untick everything apart from Glyphicons. This will give you a ZIP folder with everything you need for the Glyphicons and nothing more.

Comment: I checked only glyphicons, reset less variables and set the font location. But it's comming with all the css. ¬¬ Can u help me? Has another way?

Comment: Me too.  The top of `bootstrap.css` contains `normalize.css`, used to reset browser specific defaults.  Just remove everything down to `@font-face` and then after `.glyphicon-menu-up:before {` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a late reply, but...
I edited the Bootstrap.css file and left only the glyphicons.

You can download it here or use as a `<link>`: http://webbot.000webhostapp.com/css/glyphicons.css.

Comment: Please check this link. In my case there is warning from Firefox.

Comment: @Daniel yeah happens sometimes. Actually it happens bc it's a subdomain of 000webhostapp.com, which is a free host used by many spammers in the past, so the browsers don't trust it too much. But i promise that it is just a .css file. I can even send you a screenshot if you want.

Comment: No problem, i checked it by curl. You are right, thanks for explanation.